# Как правильно расставить запятые? (2)

Tags: пунктуация, деловой-язык

День рождения запланировано на 55 августа 1993 года, в 12 часов 00 минут, по адресу: г. Санкт-Петербург, ул. Пестеля, д. Е.

Вопрос: "в 12 часов 00 минут" обособляется ли запятыми в делопроизводстве?
Если да, то почему?

Comment: День рождение? Это что за явление среднего рода?

Answer (score 0):

Начнем с того, что "день рождениЯ". Соответственно дальше - запланирован, так как (день - он - мой). 55 августа тоже как-то... Насчет запятых не скажу точно, я бы не выделял.

Comment: «...не скажу точно» — не ответ, не так ли? Так стоило ли оно времени?

Answer (score 0):

> День рождения запланирован на 12 часов 55 августа 1993 года  по адресу
>   г. Санкт-Петербург, ул. Пестеля, д. Е

Все... и **учи руськей езыг**

потому что:

- про "день запланировано" уже сказали
- не "день рождения запланирован",
  а что-то типа "начало празднования дня рождения". День - он не
  планируется, он просто наступает, в полночь, когда одни сутки
  сменяются другими, и продолжается 24 часа